# Google Apps Engine - How many custom domains can be assigned to an app

Tags: google-app-engine

I couldnt find official information about this:

does anybody know how many different custom domains can be assigned to a GAE app ?

gae app name: "MyGAEApp"

```
custom domain 1: "myCustomDomain1.com" --> MyGAEApp
custom domain 2: "myCustomDomain2.com" --> MyGAEApp
custom domain 3: "myCustomDomain3.com" --> MyGAEApp
custom domain n: "myCustomDomainN.com" --> MyGAEApp
```

Can one assign more than 200 domains pointing to the same app ?
(dont judge the question please, it is important to know)

thank you

Comment: You do know that you can use https connections only if a custom domain has its own Google Apps account? I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, so just pointing this out.

Comment: Ok, we are creating a custom webapp that can be sell to hundred clients. each client is going to have their own domain, that will point to our GAE webapp (then we will detect the domain for custom look&feel). this has nothing to do with SSL. i just need to know how many custom domains can be assigned to a gae app. thank you

Comment: Each of our clients can add your application in google apps, I don't think that there's a limitation on the number of domains.

Comment: i dont want to ask their google-account to upload my app into their account. i want my app installed and managed once just in my own google-account, and there set all custom domains.

Comment: If your app uses passwords or works with any sensitive data, you will need SSL.

Comment: Andrei, are you saying that SSL certificates can only be installed for google apps domains ? what if a regular gmail user wants to develop a gae app ?